# How to create localhost

Tags: networking, localhost, smtp

I am trying to set up a temporary SMTP server to send an email. I am using python for this (smtplib.SMTP('localhost')) and getting a socket error. When I try wget localhost, I get a "failed: Connection refused" error. /etc/hosts has 127.0.0.1 localhost. I am using chrubuntu, and don't believe I have done anything that would modify localhost.

Comment: you might use [`smtpd`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtpd.html) instead of `smtplib`

Comment: Firstly, I'm using code slightly modified from the python docs for howto send an email. Secondly, I don't see how that explains why wget and links reveal nothing, when I think they should say something exists.

Comment: `wget` would only indicate presence or absence of a webserver (not a mailserver) surely? AFAIK `smtplib` implements a *client* - the sample program appears to assume you already have an SMTP *server* running on `localhost`.

Comment: Question does not make sense: you don't "create" localhost; your machine *is* the localhost.  `wget` says the connection is refused because you aren't running a web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you want to use the SMTP service on your local computer and this service does not exist!

So, ou need to install the SMTP daemon

```
apt-get install opensmtpd
```

then, you need to start it using

```
sudo smtpd
```

and now, your command should work.